# I want to work on my Wordpress using my shared hosting space and then do a backup and upload it in my client hosting space, is that possible?

Tags: website-design

I want to work on my Wordpress using my shared hosting space and then do a backup and upload it in my client hosting space, is that possible? I am novice and I am struggling in how get working on the website before launching it, I read about MAMP but not sure if it will do the trick, I just want to be able to work on the website and once is ready I can upload it without hassle. Can anyone help me with some tips?

Comment: You should ask on [wordpress.se], but your question is very broad

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about servers and hosting and not about design. It may be on topic on [sf], [webmasters.se], or [wordpress.se], but please check their guidelines before asking there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like JaneDoe1337, I like to work in a subdirectory of the live hosting space, but if that's not possible, I have found [All-in-One WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) to be almost one-click turnkey. You may still have to do some fussing with link paths, but it's extremely easy to use.

Comment: That's a really good tip, I was thinking in using a subdirectory and then when the site is ready I could migrate everything to the new hosting account, it seems that this plugin will do the trick and I won't need to use MAMP.

Comment: @LuMicheau If you like my answer, click on the up arrow to upvote it; if you think this is the "right" answer to your question, click on the check mark. That's how the Stack Exchange interface works. :) You can upvote many answers but only choose one "right" answer.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is not the right stack, I do have the answer for you.

Yes, it's possible to 'move' a wordpress website from one location to another. Is it 100% without a hassle? No. There's no one-click solution and it asks for some tweaking, but it's not too bad.

I like to use live hosting space so I can share my progress with my client. If you are not interested in this you can use MAMP to create a local wordpress website, which is fairly easy to use.

Comment: Thanks Jane, I posted in the web development stack and got some other opinions including to stick with MAMP or try Docker, I will use a subdirectory of my hosting space and then try the All - in -One -Plugin and give it a try in MAMP and Docker to see what works better, I just want to find the easiest way to do it.